# How to treat image blob column mySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have a SQL table `imgTbl` where one of the columns has the type `MEDIUMBLOB`. I populated the column with:

```
LOAD_FILE(“E:/wamp64/tmp/test.jpg”));
```

Question: I want to use this image in PHP. I read that I have to `<?php echo base64_encode(...); ?>` the image data, but how do I single out that column to encode when I have other columns, too? My php query is the following:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM imgTbl";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (!$result) {
      die("Database query failed.");
    }
  $rows = array();
   while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      // If $rows["image"] then encode??
      $rows[] = $subject;
   }
   echo $json_response = json_encode($rows);
```

The echo is then passed on to javascript, therefore the final JSON format.

Comment: I need to know, is this really your actual code? `LOAD_FILE(“E:/wamp64/tmp/test.jpg”));` - If so, those curly quotes are choking your code and error reporting would have told you about it. Use regular quotes `"`.

Comment: Yes, I do not know why they appeared curly when I copied them here. But they are actually normal quotes. There was no error shown when inserting the file.

Comment: use php's error reporting and add `mysqli_error($conn)` to your query, see if anything comes of it.

Comment: `$subject` is an associative array in your while loop, so just do: `$subject['image']` to get that column. If the image column is called `image`, that is.

Comment: If I take out the blob column, everything runs normal. You mean just echo mysqli_error($conn) before the other echo? Nothing shows up.

Comment: The blob contains binary data, so if you have that data in your array when you do `json_encode()`, it won't be pretty. In your loop, do: `$subject['image'] = base64_encode($subject['image'])` before you add it to your `$rows`-array.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: how do I use the $subject['image']. Do I just change the code to `row[] = base64_encode($subject['image'])`?

Comment: By not be pretty do you mean it is not going to work? I am using it in javascript later so as long as it can deal with it I am good.

Comment: I have teamviewer if anybody wants to take a look.

Comment: Do you only want the image? Then simply do `$rows[] = base64_encode($subject['image']);`. The biggest question is why you have the images in the database, to begin with? It's rarely a good choice.

Comment: No I need all the data of the associative array, not just the image. How do I do that, with an `if-function`?

Comment: I told you that in my second comment.

Comment: Ok but when I replace `$rows[] = $subject;` with `$rows[] = base64_encode($subject['image']);`, I only get the image echoed. But I need all of the data?

Comment: Or does it then base64 encode all the data?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

Storing an image in a MYSQL database is no different from storing any other type of file. When you store the image, you need to also store the content-type using [mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php). This will allow you to *properly* reconstruct the image when you retrieve it from the database.

You can't simply echo the binary data of the image to the page because in that form, it means nothing.

When a webpage displays an image, it is because your browser sent a GET request to the server, and the server returned content with an *image mime-type*.

You can easily use a URI in the `<image>` tag to point to the raw binary data like this:

```
<img src="data:<?php echo $imageMimeType; ?> ; base64, <?php echo $binaryImage; ?>">
```

Notice that in the above tag, the mime type is specified.

A few suggestions:

- Start using PDO
- Your current mysqli query will return *all* of the images and *all* of the other associated fields from the entire table. I *think* you may have intended to use a `where` clause.
- Storing images in the databse is cumbersome and generally files are not good candidates for databases. Although images may be small, the filesystem is usually the best candidate for storing them. You can easily set up a folder structure to store images and use the database to store their paths.

Comment: My plan for this approach was to assign this echo to a variable in javascript `$http.post("getData.php").success(function (data) {
      $scope.projects = data;
      console.log($scope.myList);
    });` and then use it in an angular ng-repeat. My mainpage is actually not in php, but html, and I planned to use an inline `data:image/png;base64,{{listElement.image}}` to convert it back. Would this work without pdo and mime?

Comment: it will work without PDO, I recommended using it because it is the most up-to-date method of accessing databases in PHP, and (i may be mistaken) MYSQLi is deprecated. It is important to understand that you must tell the browser what the content is, regardless of the method you provide it (php, js, angular). If I send you a song without the ".mp3" at the end, and without telling you it's a song, how can you ever listen to it? In your example, `image/png` *is* the mime type. Just make sure it changes if the image type changes (ie png, jpg, gif...)